# How do I run and debug NodeJS projects from Visual Studio through a set of scripts instead of "npm start"?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-2019, npm-start

Using Visual Studio 2019, I have downloaded all the dependencies needed to run NodeJS scripts and all works well. I can only run each `.js` script from VS (Ctrl+F5), but I want to know whether its possible to run a series of scripts like I would normally do via command prompt using `npm start`, but in real-time through VS? It's very important to me that I do not modify any script file in order to make this work, but rather let VS do the job instead of `npm start`, if It's possible at all.

I already have a project setup which I can successfully run via command prompt with `npm start`, but can I run and debug it with VS?

My main goal is to get any console output and even use breakpoints, aka. properly debug my code.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay. I am very busy at the moment, but will try it out as soon as I can. I won't leave you hanging. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and if you have any concern, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 2):

**Actually**, in **VS IDE**, there is a default node js project template that **Microsoft** provided.

[image]

You only have to install the workload Node.js development on the **vs_installer** so that you can use that template.

[image]

I think you should create such project template which follows the rule of VS IDE with `node.js`. And then migrate your old project's content into this new project.

**Note**: in this project, there is no such easy way to start several js files at the same time unless you nest nested js methods in the starting js file. And other types of projects do the same.

**If** you want to debug other js files, you only need to right-click on the file on the **Solution Explorer**. Every time switch like this, you can debug other js files.

[image]

**You** do not have to use `npm start` in this way and just click **Debug** to debug the project.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about Visual studio, but you can debug on Visual Studio Code.
you can debug from run menu.

Comment: I know about VS Code, but my question has nothing to do with it.