How to debug Node JavaScript code in Visual Studio 2022
I have a very simple single JavaScript file that I want to run with Node.js and debug in Visual Studio 2022.
I can do this fine with Visual Studio Code. To run and debug in Visual Studio Code I:

Open a new "JavaScript Debug Terminal" instance
Navigate to the correct location of the script
Run with node index.js -s 'some_input_parameter'

I cannot seem to replicate this behavior in Visual Studio 2022 although I'm guessing it is something simple I'm missing because it's got to be possible.
So far I have tried executing a similar command on the "Developer PowerShell" terminal. This runs the code fine but it does not debug the code. i.e. It does not break on breakpoints.

Did anything change from VS2019? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64912744/215552

I don't have a nodejs project which is what that answer refers to. This is simply a single JavaScript file.

Visual Studio is geared toward projects. It's kind of how it was engineered. VSCode  is more geared toward loosely-coupled groups of files

So it's just not possible to do without a nodejs project / solution?

I expect you could by manually attaching the debugger to the NodeJS debugger port. The question is, why? You already have VS Code working. There are instructions on Node's site about enabling JS debugging in a wide variety of IDEs (including Visual Studio).

To debug node.js in Visual Studio 2022 you need to use NodeJS Tools for Visual Studio(NVTS). NVTS is available as a workload in VS Installer however you need to create a project to enable this tool for visualized debugging and extensive features. It is unsupported for NTVS to debug a single file which is not part of a project.
